# odoo 8 radio widget is not coming horizontally

Tags: xml, radio-button, widget, odoo-8

Here is xml code. I am unable to get the radio buttons horizontally. Only the text is shown horizontally but the buttons are shown vertically. But it works in Odoo 9.

```
<record id="view_employee_form_inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
     <field name="name">hr.employee.form.inherited</field>
     <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
     <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form"/>
     <field name="arch" type="xml">
         <xpath expr="//field[@name='work_phone']" position="after">
            <group string="Employee Rating">
                <div><h4> Rating Scale: </h4><p> 1. Needs Improvement  2. Average  3. Good   4. Excellent  5. Extrodinary </p></div>
            </group>
            <group><field name="rating" widget="radio"  options="{'horizontal': true}"/></group>
         </xpath>
     </field>
</record>
```

Comment: I think may be the  options="{'horizontal': true}" is only for the odoo 9.0 but not in odoo 8.0

Comment: Is there any option for odoo 8?

Comment: I do not think so ..

Comment: ok fine Chaitanya..